# Can i bring Google Colab codes to Microsoft Fabric? Or only locals IDEs

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, microsoft-fabric

I have some code in Google Colab and would like to have it in Microsoft Fabric. But I did not find a direct connector.

It's possible? Or do I need to unload and load them into Fabric? It would be interesting to have a direct connector.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no connector directly of Google Colab, you'll have to export them and import them manually. You can link Google Colab to git then use the github integration in Fabric
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/cicd/git-integration/intro-to-git-integration